# DateTime returning Total days instead of Remaining days in PHP

Tags: php, date, pdo, datediff, date-difference

I have a MySQL DB which stores Warranty dates. The values are Start_Date and End_Date, I'm trying to calculate the Days of Warranty remaining.

Example:

- Invoice 0001
- Warranty Start (2018-12-01)
- Warranty End (2019-01-11)
- Output: Warranty Expires in 2 Days (assuming 2019-01-09 is current)

**Try #1 - DateTime**

```
#date_1 = 2018-12-01 (From MySQL) - Start / PAST
#date_2 = 2019-01-11 (From MySQL) - End / FUTURE

$d1 = new DateTime($date_1);
$d2 = new DateTime($date_2);

$int = date_diff($d1, $d2);
$r = $int->format('In %a days');
```

> **Output In 41 days**

**Try #2 - Date_Create**

```
#date_1 = 2018-12-01 (From MySQL) - Start / PAST
#date_2 = 2019-01-11 (From MySQL) - End / FUTURE

$d1 = date_create($date_1);
$d2 = date_create($date_2);

$int = date_diff($d1, $d2);

return $int->format('%a');
```

> **Output 41**

**Try #3 - SQL DATEDIFF**

```
$data = $pdo->query("
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(start_date, end_date) 
AS date_difference 
FROM `warranty` 
ORDER BY id 
DESC
")->fetchAll();
```

> **Output -41**

What am I doing wrong? I simply want to calculate the amount of days left on Invoice Warranty.

Comment: There are 41 days between 1st December 2018 and 11th January 2019, so what's the issue ?

Comment: @JulesR Read the very bottom, really explains. I would not be asking this if I was getting needed results. I wan't to find the "Days Remaining" on the Warranty

Comment: Invert start and end ?

Comment: I guess you wouldn't be asking that if you had read the documentation: https://sql.sh/fonctions/datediff

Comment: It's not clear from your code, but are you saying you want to know the days left from today's date? Because if so, you need to use the current date instead of a date in the past.

Comment: @JulesR Like I can clearly read French *slow clap* but that link is actually wrong. I would have to do DATEDIFF(end_date, NOW()) AS date_difference

Comment: I took the first one available. The link is right, your usage is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you need to use today for start, not a day in the past, e.g.

```
$d1 = new DateTime();
$d2 = new DateTime($date_2);

$int = date_diff($d1, $d2);
$r = $int->format('In %a days');
```

This will give you the remaining days from today until the end of the warranty.

Comment: Thank you, but I got it to work with plain SQL. I didn't realize $d1 would have to be current time, kind of figured it should be possible to take Past date and Future date and figure the days remaining till Future Date.

Answer (score 0):

Check the DATEDIFF docs:

```
date1, date2    Required. Two dates to calculate the number of days between. (date1 - date2)
```

You need:

```
DATEDIFF(end_date, start_date)
```

Comment: Thats what I have in Try #3 there placement is different then yours as its opposite but its gonna output -41 days or 41 days

Comment: @0111010001110000 the difference between 1st Dec 2018 and 11th Jan 2019 IS actually 41 days. If you want a different output, change the input. (e.g. replace end_date by today's date).